# 32k Redirects: Practical Solution

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, redirect, httpd.conf

I am currently in the process of creating a Wordpress site on the same domain as the old site. There are 32k products pages, all static html files. I want to redirect these to the corresponding individual post on Wordpress. There is no pattern between the permalink of the Wordpress posts and the old URLs so a redirect rule wouldn't work.

What is the best way to make these 32k redirects without the server grinding to a halt? (it is a dedicated server).

My first thought was to put all 32k in the .htaccess folder. I was told this WOULD slow the server down significantly. I was told that the modifying httpd.conf would be quicker. I also had the idea of creating multiple .htaccess for each subfolder I am going to redirect.

What is the best practise?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried to write some things? If yes, could you share it?

Comment: .htaccess is read on every request. Adding 32k redirects in there will not work. use RewriteMap